# UIViewAnimationTransitionCurl in left and right direction

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, uiviewanimationtransition

Is there any way possible to use UIViewAnimationTransitionCurl in left and right directions? I'm looking for something similar to the Contacts app:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are targetting iOS 5, use [`UIPageViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/UIPageViewControllerClassReference.html).  The last fifteen minutes of the *Implementing UIViewController Containment* video from [WWDC 2011](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/) describe how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind iOS 5 as a requirement you could use the new [UIPageViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/UIPageViewControllerClassReference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIPageViewController)

Otherwise you could try something like this:

```
self.appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
UIViewController *srcViewController = (UIViewController *) self.sourceViewController;
UIViewController *destViewController = (UIViewController *) self.destinationViewController;
[UIView commitAnimations];
[UIView beginAnimations:@"View Flip" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.25];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
[UIView setAnimationTransition: UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:self.appDelegate.window.rootViewController.view.superview cache:YES];
[srcViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
[UIView commitAnimations];
[self.appDelegate.window addSubview:destViewController.view];
self.appDelegate.window.rootViewController=destViewController;
```

Cheers....

Comment: actually I would change a simple UIView ...  `[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp forView:rightPage cache:YES];` does this work for UIView ?